# ActiveRecord: "WHERE IN" SQL statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following SQL statement:
`SELECT article_id FROM publications WHERE category_id IN (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE parent_id = 3)`

How to convert it to Rails ActiveRecord?

I have tried: `Article.find(:all, :conditions => ["publications.category_id IN(?)", 3], :include => [:publications])`, it returns empty array.

Models:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :publications
  has_many :categories, :through => :publications

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Category'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => :parent_id
  has_many :articles, :through => :publications
  has_many :publications


class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :category
```

Comment: Can you post your associations code (has_many, belongs_to, etc.) for Publication, Article and Category? I suspect you may have something wrong there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this working ?

```
Article.find(:all, 
             :conditions => ["publications.category_id IN(SELECT id FROM categories WHERE parent_id = ?)", 3], 
             :include => [:publications])
```

I would suggest you to use [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) to represent tree structure in database, there is also [a railcast about ancestry](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry)

Comment: @narkoz I'd still like to see your models, I think with appropriate associations you can avoid the hard-coded SQL in your :conditions.

Answer (score 0):

What do your models look like?

You'll need the associations set up correctly in your Article, Category, and Publication models.

It sounds like you have the relevant foreign keys set up in your tables, but your models don't know to look for the association

Comment: I don't think that's right - based on the SELECT statement, it looks to me like his Publication belongs_to :category and Category has_many :publications. Need to see his associations.

Comment: 10-4. Oops, hadn't refreshed.